# Change Image From Previous View After Button Tap (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to the image thats in my UIImageView on my previous View after I tap on a button.

Any help? Thanks.

**MainViewController.swift**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var hatBackground: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        hatBackground.image = UIImage(named: "black-hat-front.jpg")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showPatches"{
            if let childViewController = segue.destination as? ChildViewController{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ChildViewController.swift**

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var doubleCupButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Choose a Patch"
    }

    @IBAction func doubleCupButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        hatBackground.image = UIImage(named: "badgal-hat.jpg")??

        // Go back to previous Controller
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I good understood , you want choose image in ChildViewController  and show it in MainViewController. To do that you should implement delegate pattern like this:

### MainViewController

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, ChildViewControllerDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var hatBackground: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    hatBackground.image = UIImage(named: "black-hat-front.jpg")
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPatches"{
      if let childViewController = segue.destination as? ChildViewController{
        childViewController.delegate = self
      }
    }
  }

  func didSelectImage(image: UIImage?) {
    self.hatBackground.image = image
  }
}
```

### ChildViewController

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var doubleCupButton: UIButton!
  var delegate: ChildViewControllerDelegate?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Choose a Patch"
  }

  @IBAction func doubleCupButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "badgal-hat.jpg")
    delegate?.didSelectImage(image: selectedImage)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
  }
}
```

### ChildViewControllerDelegate

```
protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate {
  func didSelectImage(image:UIImage?)
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!